# Storing value from an html text input in a PHP variable using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to obtain the value in an html text input in real time (without submitting a form) and store it in a PHP variable. I'm doing all of this within the same php file (home.php). The script doesn't return any errors. However, when I try to access the value through the global POST array, I get an error that says the index 'query' is undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    function getQuery(){
    $('#query').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "home.php",
           data: {query:$(this).val()}
        });
    });
    }
}
</script>

<input name='searchBar' type='text' onChange='getQuery();' size='100' id='query'></input>

<?php
    $x = $_POST['query'];
    echo $x;
?>
```

Comment: You need to use conditionals so you don't output when you dont want to. You also only want to return the `x` on submission.

Comment: I specified that the program requires that no form submission occurs. The data exchange has to happen in real time.

Comment: What are you really trying to do.  You can't store a variable in a post array the way you trying to.  The $_POST array holds values of a form on a SUBMIT action.

Comment: `$.ajax({` is a submit, just not traditional.

Comment: @chris85 ok, good to know.  But will the $_POST be updated from the ajax?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a program like [link]https://www.neverendingchartrendering.org/[/link] so I need the search bar to return the album results while the user types information in.

Comment: @joesph, yes, that is still sending as a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED***

home.php

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#query").on('keyup', function(){

        $.ajax({

          type: 'POST',
          url: 'search.php',
          data: {query:$(this).val()},
          success: function(data) {

            $("#display").html(data);

          }

        });
    });

  });

</script>


<input id="query" name="query" type="text" size="100"></input>

<div id="display"></div>
```

search.php

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['query'];
echo 'You made it to your search page.  x = ' . $x;
?>
```

Comment: It's still showing the same error, so I'm going to try out having the AJAX portion in search.php like you said.

Comment: So, I have split the code like you have it in your updated answer and I'm no longer getting the Notice: undefined index 'query' message. However, search.php is not echoing out the value when I type in the text box.

Comment: So I have updated my code, I forgot the success function, also there was a stray paren in there.  Sorry for typos..  Also I dont think you need the semi colon after the getQuery function in the input.  Make sure you have your console open or you won't see the results.

Comment: @Matthias Quintero  I updated my answer again, this is a working solution on my machine.  Also notice that I added the jQuery library.

Comment: I have the console open and I'm not seeing any values logged. Here is a screenshot of the console with some text I typed into the input [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VrKYhTuHnoYkNgkElOcdLGusPKapFPmm)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168258/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-matthias-quintero).